# observing and assigning properties

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, frp, rx-swift

In an ObjC project I am using this ReactiveCocoa pattern

```
RAC(self.pagingControl, currentPage) = RACObserve(self.pagingView, index);
```

What's the Swift equivalent with RAC4 and RxSwift?
I am a bit lost in the docs on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RAC 4 you use the MutableProperty generic type, you can then bind these to signals using the `<~` operator. You can also observe these properties as signals or as signal producers using `.signal` and `.producer` respectively, access their current value with `.value` and change their value with `.swapValue(_)`